# How to get target result with SQL query with JOIN statement

Tags: sql

Trying solve #12 on http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/The_JOIN_operation

*"For every match where 'GER' scored, show matchid, match date and the number of goals scored by 'GER'"*

This is what I have in the query box:

```
SELECT matchid, mdate, COUNT(player)
FROM game 
JOIN goal 
ON game.matchid = goal.id 
WHERE (team1 = 'GER' OR team2 = 'GER')
GROUP BY matchid
```

I keep getting "Wrong answer. Some of the data is incorrect." Can you help? Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to control for games where GER scored, not just games where they were playing.  You're counting the total number of goals scored in any games where GER was playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment:

```
Select a.matchID, b.mdate, count(*) as Goals
from goal a
inner join game b
on a.matchID = b.ID
where a.teamID = 'GER'
group by a.matchID, b.mdate
```

You need to start with the goals scored by GER, then join to get the other info about the match.  Your answer starts with the games GER was playing, which isn't what is being requested.

Comment: Hi @APH, thank you! you're right about it has to be specific on goals by GER.

Comment: Will do. Thank you again! Also please give an upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with APH's help, I revised my original code to:

```
SELECT matchid, mdate, COUNT(player)
FROM game 
JOIN goal 
ON game.id = goal.matchid
WHERE (team1 = 'GER' OR team2 = 'GER') AND teamid = 'GER'
GROUP BY matchid
```

I added "teamid = 'GER'" to the WHERE statement. 
Thanks again!